# Installed Java SE 7u10, still seing 7u10ea on OS X?

Tags: java, installation, version, jdk, osx-mountain-lion

when I type `java -version`I still get the *Early Access* version and not the stable JDK 7u10. please how to fix that ? I am working on *Mac OS X Mountain Lion*.

`ls /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions`

- 1.5.0
- 1.6
- 1.6.0
- A <-- ?
- Current <-- ?
- CurrentJDK <-- ?

What the **?** stands for please ?

`/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    1.7.0_10, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_10.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_37-b06-434, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_37-b06-434, i386: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_10.jdk/Contents/Home
```

The problem is `java -version` --> `java version "1.7.0_10-ea"` **EA** !

The worst is that `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_10.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version` show me the **EA**.

Comment: Check your system path. I am betting that the newer JDK is not part of the path statement yet.

Comment: check what exactly please ?

Comment: I found this interesting folder : `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ... ?

Comment: What OS are you working on? If windows, then open a command window, and type in `path<return>`

Comment: I am working on MAc OS X Mountain Lion

Comment: I made an `echo $PATH`

Comment: What does `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` have to say?

Comment: I updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.7 JDKs don't go into `/System/Library/Frameworks`, they go into `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`.  When you run `/usr/bin/java` it picks the appropriate Java installation to use

- If you have a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable set, then it will use that version
- otherwise it will choose the "best" installed JDK out of the ones available in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` and `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`, you can run `/usr/libexec/java_home` to see which one the system considers to be "best".

Of course, if you have manually added `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<something>/Contents/Home/bin` to your `PATH` ahead of `/usr/bin` then `java` will mean that specific version rather than the one selected by the system.  You can check this by running `which java`.

To complicate matters further, there's another copy of the JRE in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`, which is the one used for browser plugins and for 1.7-style `.app` bundles that don't embed their own JRE.

Comment: It found three installed Java Virtual Machine but it picks a different one. It found `JVM 1.7.0u10` and it picks `JVM 1.7.0u10ea`

Comment: When I do `java -version`I get `1.7.0_10-ea` I need to get `1.7.0_10` !

Comment: @ALJIMohamed and is `java` definitely `/usr/bin/java`?  Try `which java` to find that out.

Comment: which java --> `/usr/bin/java` .

Comment: I have never done anything manually.

Comment: @ALJIMohamed If you have the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable set then that will take precedence over the usual discovery mechanism.  Does `unset JAVA_HOME` help?

Comment: no and I think I had it not set.

Comment: `ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`I have one **JDK** and it is **EA**.

Comment: @ALJIMohamed at this point all I can suggest is that you delete `jdk1.7.0_10.jdk` from `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` and then re-install it from a fresh download.  I've just tried installing it myself and I don't get `-ea`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21485/discussion-between-alji-mohamed-and-ian-roberts)

Comment: I will give it a try ...